# how would I post multiple values using $_Post and then use these values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I am creating a website using html,css,php,mysql and javascript with little bits of jquery.
at the moment I have 3 drop down boxes that dynamically show you options for Example if I click english then the next drop down box shows all sections for english such as reading and then the next one will be related to reading this is all working perfectly.

What I am trying to do is use the values for each of these drop down boxes in a sql query to the return the specific videos that are related to these drop down boxes.

what type of array would I need to use for the $_Post and how would the sql query be structured so i can pull down all the information for the videos.

This is the code that I am currently using for the drop down menus

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#category").change(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });
        });

         $("select#principle").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").change(function(){
            $("select#principle").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#principle").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_principle.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#principle").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#principle").html(data);
            });
        });

        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
            var princ = $("select#principle option:selected").attr('value');
            if(cat>0 && type>0 && princ>0)
            {
                var result = $("select#principle option:selected").html();
                $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form id="select_form">
            Choose a category:<br />
            <select id="category">
                <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
            </select>
        <br /><br />

        Choose a type:<br />
        <select id="type">
             <option value="%">any...</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        Choose a principle:<br />
        <select id="principle">
             <option value="%">any...</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the section that runs the sql queries

```
<?php
class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->DbConnect();
        }

        protected function DbConnect()
        {
            include "db_config.php";
            $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
            mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
            return TRUE;
        }

        public function ShowCategory()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM subject";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $category = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $category .= '<option value="' . $row['subject_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $category;
        }

        public function ShowType()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM section WHERE subject_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $type = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $type .= '<option value="' . $row['section_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $type;
        }

         public function ShowPrinciple()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM principle WHERE section_id=$_POST[id]";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $principle = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $principle .= '<option value="' . $row['principle_id'] . '">' . $row['description'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $principle;
        }   
}

$opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

Comment: I guess someone voted down because you did not provided any code to illustrate your question/problem.

Comment: 1) Accept the options, and access them with `$_POST` superglobal array, 2) Escape all the user input, 3) Create the query, 4) Execute it. Which part exactly are you having troubles with?

Comment: @Brice i have edited the question with the examples of my code would their be anything else needed

Comment: @AmalMurali all of it to be honest i am new to php i would just like to be pointed in the right direction maybe a couple examples that i can learn from.

Comment: @user3266354: If you're new to PHP, I suggest you google for some tutorials and try to learn the absolute basics first. The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php) is a good place to start. When you're having troubles with a specific problem, you can always google: `how to do X php`. Searching through the questions on Stack Overflow will help, too. Good luck!

Comment: If you are new to php you should skip the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and go straight to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements. Now you have a serious sql injection problem.

Comment: @jeroen right this second I am ok using the mysql_* functions because this is just a demo that i am trying to put together the full version i will be using mysqli. I am using mysql_* until i have learnt mysqli to a sufficient level

Comment: PS - Download MySQL Workbench - it's a heck of a lot easier than phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something basic:

HTML - create the interface to gather your data

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> (put in head)

<div class='nameinput'>Name: <input type=text /></div>
<div class='ageinput'>Age: <input type=text /></div>
<button id = 'clickme'>CLICK</button>
```

JS - gather the data and present to php with ajax

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  var username =  $('.nameinput').val();
  var userage =  $('.ageinput').val();
  $.ajax({
          url: 'nameofphpfile.php',
         type: POST,
         data: { name: username,
                 age: userage },
     dataType: 'json'
          })
            .done(function(){ alert('Great job!')  })
            .fail(function(){ alert('The server does not like you!) });
                                });
```

(NB: The more difficult part for me was understanding the callbacks - I've switched to the "newer" forms of .done, .fail, .always).

```
PHP - grab the data passed from client with ajax, and put in the db.

<!php
$name   = $_POST['username'];
$age    = $_POST['userage'];

$host        = "xxxxx";
$user        = "xxxxx";
$password    = "xxxxx";
$dbname      = "xxxxx";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " INSERT INTO nameofyourtable
     ( name, age)
     VALUES
     ('$name', '$age') " ;
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");
?>
```

The approach is different if you want to read data, but that's a different question.

Best of luck!

I went through this about a year ago, so I know what you're going through.